# Edit boxes do not set a foreground color and thus are unreadable

Tags: bug, design

Several input boxes and textareas on security.SE and meta.security.SE have a CSS problem: They set a white background color, but do not set a foreground color. Thus the text is rendered with the user's *default foreground color*. When that color is white, the textareas and input boxes are unreadable.

This seems to affect:

- The input box for entering question titles
- The textarea for entering questions and answers
- The textarea for entering tags

I've seen a few isolated cases of this elsewhere on the network, but it is most pronounced here. It was quite difficult to even compose this question.

This can be trivially reproduced by setting a "dark" desktop theme, such as Windows' High Contrast Inverse theme, that defaults to a white foreground and black background, or by making the equivalent change in the browser preferences.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The comment box also suffers from the same problem...